# get_posts / WP_Query Memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, get-posts, cron

I want to get all post IDs of my product pages. But either the first way or the second way are succesfull...

I always get:

```
PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8388616 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1842
```

First way:

```
if ( ! defined('ABSPATH') ) {
    /** Set up WordPress environment */
    require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-load.php' );
}

$posts_array = get_posts(array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        ));

$myfile = fopen("wp_all_import.txt", "a");

foreach ($posts_array as $value) {
    fwrite($myfile, $posts_array . "\n");
}

fclose($myfile);
```

Second way:

```
if ( ! defined('ABSPATH') ) {
    /** Set up WordPress environment */
    require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-load.php' );
}

$products_IDs = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        ));
$myfile = fopen("wp_all_import.txt", "a");

while ($products_IDs->have_posts() ) : $products_IDs->the_post();
fwrite($myfile, get_the_ID() . "\n");
endwhile; wp_reset_query();

fclose($myfile);
```

Does anybody know where is my failure and how I can fix that?
I just want to get all the post IDs of my product posts.

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: Do you get memory error with `'posts_per_page' => 10` ? The `'fields' => 'ids'`  gives you only the IDs.

Comment: No, i just tried it.

Comment: How many products are there? The wp-cli is also a handy tool for exporing if you like working with the command line.

Comment: 2100 products. But I can not use the handy tool because I need to program a cronjob!

Comment: Did using the fields parameter made any difference? Note  that you should write to file only once, not 2100 times.

Comment: No, it did't. But how can I fix the problem? - I need to loop through all products..

Comment: When debugging you have to remove/add code parts and adjust various values, to see what exactly is causing the error. You can also try increasing the allowed WP memory usage (many answers about that here on this site). It's possible to fetch data from db with wpdb.  It looks like you want to save the post ID's to a file, then why not create an array/string with looping first and then write that once. Best of luck

Comment: I already tried that. But is it possible that 2100 products are crashing my 134mb ram?

Comment: yes, it looks like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If all you want is printing ID in a file, then you may write custom query for it. That way you'll be able to avoid some internal processing WordPress does.
2. Many posts may exhaust your RAM, although I don't think just selecting ID of 2100 posts should really eat up 134MB RAM. Just do the math, `ID` can be saved in just 1 byte, but lets say it's taking 4 bytes. Still, 2100 x 4 = 8400 Bytes = 8.4 KB. Obviously PHP needs more internal memory to process, to create objects etc. But with 134MB memory, I could easily process few hundred thousand ID. So obviously you are doing wrong somewhere else.

Anyways, for whatever reason (may be you need to select everything from `product`, not just ID), you may segment the query with limits. Like the following CODE:

```
if ( ! defined('ABSPATH') ) {
    /** Set up WordPress environment */
    require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-load.php' );
}
// $limit determines how many rows you want to handle at any given time
// increase / decrease this limit to see how much your server can handle at a time 
$limit = 100;
$start = 0;

// open file handle
$myfile = fopen( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp_all_import.txt', 'a' );

$qry = "SELECT ID FROM `$wpdb->posts` where post_type='post' AND post_status='publish' limit %d, %d";
while( $result = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( $qry, array( $start, $limit ) ) ) ) {
    $write_data = '';
    foreach ( $result as $row ) {
        $write_data = $write_data . $row->ID . "\n";
    }
    // Generally speaking, writing immidiately to the file is better than
    // string concatination, because depending on what you concat and how many times,
    // the generated string may become too big (like MB size string).
    // On the other hand, writing to files thousands of times in a single script may
    // cause I/O delays. So, here I've done a combination of the two to keep both
    // string size & I/O within limits.
    // Adjust this according to your own situation.
    fwrite( $myfile, $write_data );
    $start = $start + $limit;
}

// close file handle
fclose( $myfile );
```

This way PHP will only handle maximum `$limit` number of rows, so memory limit should not cross.

> ***Note:*** never ever concatenate to make very long strings (like MB long), write immediately to the file before it becomes too long. It may produce some I/O delay, but it'll not exhaust memory limit.

Comment: yes I agree, we should be careful constructing too long string values, easy to eat up the memory that way ;-) but I've also experienced various slow I/O because some installs I work with have upload folders mounted to external disks, but I haven't checked how it would react to very large number of file writes. In general I would try to avoid running code in the global scope and try to hook it from a plugin instead of a custom file. Interesting approach how you used `sprintf` instead of `wpdb->prepare`  to use a placeholder for the table name ;-)

Comment: I/O in a shared hosting will cause headaches too. So I guess it'll depend on the situation. Perhaps a combination of some concatenation + some writes will be the best approach.

Comment: @birgire updated the CODE with `wpdb->prepare` anyway. Who knows, may be someone will use it in the future and then blame me for their problems. So thanks for the mention :) BTW, couldn't have used table name with `wpdb->prepare` anyway, because quote with table name is not valid syntax.

Comment: yes it's hard to say how people use the snippets here ;-) but I've started to distrust my own test input values; as it usually change as I develop snippets further and they can end as user inputs ;-) But I think your sprintf use was fine ;-)

Comment: I want to test your code but do not understand the term `$wpdb->posts`. Where did you define `$wpdb` and if I use my table name, how can I call a function on it like `->posts`? - What should I insert instand of `$wpdb->posts`? - My Table name is `fWR6qIN_posts`

Comment: Okay, I got it. It is a class. But why I do not get any written lines to my file?

http://gamekeys-shop.de/wp_all_import.txt

Comment: Did you check to see if this line `$myfile = fopen( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp_all_import.txt', 'a' );` corresponds to the same file of `gamekeys-shop.de/wp_all_import.txt`? Also, is that file writable? Check it.